# Login to MobileFirst server with Facebook/Twitter

Tags: facebook, websphere, ibm-mobilefirst, websphere-portal, ltpa

What is recommended way to Sign in / Log in to MobileFirst Server with e.g. Facebook, or Twitter? My MobileFirst Server is associated with WebspherePortal (LDAP).

Now I'm using [WebSphere LTPA-based authentication](https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-6-3/authentication-security/websphere-ltpa-based-authentication/)
to login to MF, and everything works fine, but I want to allow users to log in with social media accounts too.

In official page developer.ibm.com (Authentication and security section) there is no suggestion how to connect with social network account.

Comment: Two possible implementations, for Twitter and LinkedIn (not Facebook) can be found here: - search for "Using twitter": https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/2015/06/18/mobilefirst-tweet-notifications/
- LinkedIn: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/mo-worklight-linkedin/

Comment: thanks for answer, but in my case it's not enough. Your examples shows, how to obtain access token from Twitter/linked_in and gets e.g. twitts. What I try to do is connect MobileFirst server account with e.g. Twitter account.

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in mechanism in MobileFirst Platform Foundation 6.3-7.x to allow for cross social login "account" < > MobileFirst Server "user identity account" communication. This will have to be a custom implementation to do.

That said, in MobileFirst Foundation 8.0 this has become much simpler and there are two blog posts published with two methods to accomplish using Security Checks. You can find detailed information on this (which goes beyond the scope of this question so I am not writing it as part of the answer), here: https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/blog/2016/04/06/social-login-with-ibm-mobilefirst-platform-foundation/

If you must use an older release of MobileFirst Platform then I advise to read the above blog post still and see if you can re-implement it in the previous security model.